# Check to see if an element exists in a 2D array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to check to see if an character element is in my output array. The array is getting the frequency of the characters in a string. So i want to say if the current character is in the array then add 1 to the frequency else add the character to the array with a frequency of 1. Also, I want the table to display the top 5 highest frequency's in order.

EX of what the table should look like:

```
  character: a b c d
  freqency:  1 2 3 4


string input = GetInputString(inputFileName);
char ** output; 

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(output); i++)
{
      if (input [count] == output[i][]) // this is where my issue is
      {

            //.......
      }

}
```

Comment: First of all, you should initialize your `char ** output;`. Now it is just not initialized pointer to pointer to char (read about memory allocation and arrays!). And why do you need 2D array? 1D arrays are good enough for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::vector<std::pair<char,int>>` to store character and it's count.

```
string input("1212345678999");

std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> sp;
for(auto c : input)
{
  auto it = std::find_if(sp.begin(), sp.end(), 
                         [=](const pair<int, char>& p) {return p.first == c; });
  if (it != sp.end())
  {
    it->second++;  // if char is found, increase count
  }
  else
  {
    sp.push_back(std::make_pair(c, 1)); // new char, add an entry and initialize count to 1
  }
}
```

To display the top 5 highest frequency's in order, you could sort by `count` in decent order:

```
std::sort(sp.begin(), sp.end(), 
                      [](const pair<int, char>& p1, const pair<int, char>& p2)
                      {
                         return p1.second > p2.second; 
                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your example means that 'a' is at 0,0, 'b' is at 0,2, 1 is at 1,0 etc, which means that the character is always in the first row, you just have to iterate through every entry of 0[x].

```
// you should declare your array as an array
char output[2][26] = {0}; // {0} initialises all elements;
// ... assign values to output.

// I assume there's a count loop here, that checks for the upper bounds of input.
// ...
// You have to determine how many columns there are somehow, 
// I just made a static array of 2,26
const int columnsize = 26; 
for (int i = 0; i < columnsize;   i++)
{
  if ( input[count] == output[0][i] )
  {
        // found the character
  }
}
```

This is to make your implementation work, but there are better or at least easier ways to do this. For instance, if your array sizes aren't fixed at compile time, you could use a vector of vectors. Or if you just want to track the occurrences of characters, you could use a stl map of characters to frequency.

Comment: Ya, I was looking at vectors and they seem a lot easier maybe I will just try to work with those instead